# sample mean to population mean

Tags: confidence-interval

How to use sample mean to know the population mean? Now I have sample mean, sd and population mean. They are 37.28, 25 and 34. Sample size is 25
Here is my thought
N < 25. Sample mean may not equal to population mean.
population mean is 37.28 + 25/√25 =42 
Am i correct?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you're actually given the population mean, then that's what you should use for the population mean. This doesn't usually happen, though. When it doesn't, the sample mean is a *point estimator* (a single randomly chosen number which is usually close to the population mean). A *confidence interval* is an *interval estimator* (a randomly chosen interval which usually contains the population mean). Both of these are commonly used.

Comment: Yeah but in my case I think i need to find the population mean to solve my question. Here is my question.
Suppose that population sd of this waiting time is 34 minutes. Construct a 99% confidence interval for the true mean waiting time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\mu$ is

$$\large{\left[ \overline X-z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})} \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n} ,  \overline X+z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})} \cdot \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt n}\right]}$$

$z_{(1-\frac{\alpha}{2})}$ is the z-value of the standard normal distribution. $1-\alpha$ is the confidence level.

In your case $\overline X=37.28$, $\sigma=34$ and $1-\frac{\alpha}{2}=1-\frac{0.01}{2}=0.995$

Comment: @Nobi You can calculate if the population mean is inside the confidence interval. If it is the case then you can not reject that  that the sample is drawn from the population with the mean of 34 ( with a confidence level of 99%). Thus you have to look if the value of 34 is inside the interval.

Comment: um... so how to calculate the population mean?

Comment: The population mean is given. The value is 34. No calculation is needed. Have you calculated confidence interval ?

Comment: No... 34 is the population sd not mean.

Comment: Can you point out what are the values of the sample mean and the population mean ? I´m little bit confused now.

Comment: I just know the sample mean. It is 37.28.

Comment: What is 25 in "They are 37.28, **25** and 34..." ? Population mean ?

Comment: it is sample sd. sorry i didn't mention clearly

Comment: Therefore the confidence interval is $\left[ 37.28-2.58 \cdot \frac{34}{\sqrt {25}} ,  37.28+2.58 \cdot \frac{34}{\sqrt{25}}\right]$